# Is there a need for ESTA visa update when traveling to different location?

Tags: visas, esta

My ESTA visa is valid and my passport has not expired but my travel location is different from the first time. Should I update the travel information?

Comment: Your travel location in the US, you mean? I assume this is an ESTA for the US, and your holiday route has changed, or airport of arrival?

Comment: @Cmaster not sure it's a second visit, he's just changing where he's going in the US.

Comment: @mts not sure it's a second visit, he's just changing where he's going in the US.

Comment: @MarkMayo I believe "the first time" implies that this is a subsequent visit.

Comment: @phoog if you believe it's a dupe as well, why'd you write an entire answer? I agree it might, but it could also just mean 'from when I first applied for the esta'.

Comment: @MarkMayo I made the answer before I had any idea that it was a dupe.  Also I think Efthalia is a she.

Comment: I think one of those 2 marked dupes should be made  a dupe of the other

Comment: @CMaster I disagree, one of those asks specifically about the address the other about the flight details. Even though I first had the same thought I am convinced both should live in their own right, none is a dupe of the other.

Answer (score 3):

No.  Travelers "will not be required to update their destination addresses or itineraries should they change after their ESTA application has been approved."

See http://www.cbp.gov/travel/international-visitors/frequently-asked-questions-about-visa-waiver-program-vwp-and-electronic-system-travel

> Q: Can prospective travelers apply for an ESTA without specific travel plans if they want to be able to travel to the United States later on short notice?
>
> A: Yes. VWP travelers are not required to have specific plans to travel to the United States before they apply for an ESTA. If a traveler’s destination in the United States is unknown when he or she completes the ESTA application, the traveler should enter “Unknown.” Travelers may update this information when their plans are finalized, but *they will not be required to update their destination addresses or itineraries should they change after their ESTA application has been approved.* DHS recommends that ESTA applications be submitted as early as possible, as soon as, or even before travel is planned. ESTA will accept applications from last-minute and emergency travelers – those VWP travelers who arrive at the airport without an approved ESTA.

(Emphasis added)

Also note this question and answer:

> Q: Is an ESTA a visa?
>
> A: No. An approved ESTA is not a visa. It does not meet the legal or regulatory requirements to serve in lieu of a U.S. visa when a visa is required under U.S. law. Individuals who possess a valid visa will still be able to travel to the United States on that visa for the purpose for which it was issued. Individuals traveling on valid visas are not required to apply for ESTA.