# Updating USA address for second visit on ESTA

Tags: usa, esta

I have followed the '3 simple steps' to update my ESTA as I want to change the address for which I am staying at in the USA, however they just sent me a copy of my current ESTA with the old address on it and I can't find any option to update/change it. Does anybody know where this is or can help me at all?

Comment: Which "3 simple steps"? Who are "they"?

Comment: To underscore the "note" at the end of Henning Makholm's answer, you may want to consult these questions and their answers: http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/45832/do-i-need-to-change-my-esta-address-when-visiting-the-us-again; http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/53273/updating-esta-details-for-second-visit-to-usa; http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/66445/is-there-a-need-for-esta-visa-update-when-traveling-to-different-location

Answer (score 3):

Go to https://esta.cbp.dhs.gov/esta/ and click "Check existing application", "Check individual status", "Confirm".

Type in your passport number and ESTA confirmation number, or click "I do not know the application number" and type in name and citizenship too.

If you find a valid ESTA, there'll be an "update" link (not a button!) in one of the last columns of the table.

---

**Note that** you're not actually required to keep the "address in the US" information up-to-date after the ESTA is approved.